# C, doubly linked list problem

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to read input from the user about a customer.

Input: mike,404 forbidden st,raleigh,nc,27607,123.78

Then add that customer to a alphabetically sorted, doubly linked list. The user can choose to insert an entry, delete and entry, or view the list. After adding the user control...my sscanf doesn't work properly anymore. I can not figure out why. I don't understand why I'm not able to print customer values in the user control version.

Also, any advice/links about the syntax of updating a nodes previous field would be very helpful :P

Thank you in advance

Working (without user control):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXNAMELEN 19
#define MAXADDRLEN 49
#define MAXCITYLEN 19
#define MAXSTATELEN 2

struct aNode {
    char name[MAXNAMELEN];
    char address[MAXADDRLEN];
    char city[MAXCITYLEN];
    char state[MAXSTATELEN];
    int zip;
    float balance;
    struct aNode *next;
    struct aNode *prev; 
};

typedef struct aNode node;
struct aNode *dLList;

void read();
void input();
void print();
void delete();
int insertSort(node*);

int main() {

    //from text file
    read();

    input();  
        /*
    int choice;
    while(1) {
        printf("\n1.INSERT\n2.DELETE\n3.DISPLAY\n4.END\n");
        printf("Enter choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            input();
            break;
        case 2:
            delete();
            break;
        case 3:
            print();
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    */
    return(0);
}

//TODO
void read() {

}

void input() {

    struct aNode *current;
    current = (struct aNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct aNode));

    int buff = 120;
    char temp[buff];

    printf("Enter data: ");
    fgets(temp, buff, stdin);
    sscanf(temp, "%[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %d%*c %f", 
           current->name, current->address, current->city, current->state,   
           &current->zip, &current->balance);                   

    insertSort(current);

    //only for testing
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %5d, $%9.2f\n", 
            current->name, current->address, current->city, 
            current->state, current->zip, current->balance);
}

void print() {

    struct aNode *p;

    for(p = dLList; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %5d, $%9.2f\n", 
               p->name, p->address, p->city, 
               p->state, p->zip, p->balance);
    }
}

//TODO
void delete() {

}

int insertSort(node * current) {

     struct aNode *p;
    struct aNode *q;

    p = (struct aNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct aNode));
    p = current;

    //need to link to previous node   
    if(dLList == NULL || strcmp(dLList->name, p->name) > 0) {
        p->next = dLList;
        p->prev = NULL;
        return(0);
    }else {
        q = dLList;
        while(q->next != NULL && strcmp(q->next->name, q->name) < 0) {
            q = q->next;
        }   
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next = p;
        return(0);
    }   
}
```

Output: mike, 404 forbidden st, raleigh, nc, 27607, $   123.78

Not Working (with user control):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXNAMELEN 19
#define MAXADDRLEN 49
#define MAXCITYLEN 19
#define MAXSTATELEN 2

struct aNode {
    char name[MAXNAMELEN];
    char address[MAXADDRLEN];
    char city[MAXCITYLEN];
    char state[MAXSTATELEN];
    int zip;
    float balance;
    struct aNode *next;
    struct aNode *prev; 
};

typedef struct aNode node;
struct aNode *dLList;

void read();
void input();
void print();
void delete();
int insertSort(node*);

int main() {

    //from text file
    read();

    //input();

    int choice;
    while(1) {
        printf("\n1.INSERT\n2.DELETE\n3.DISPLAY\n4.END\n");
        printf("Enter choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            input();
            break;
        case 2:
            delete();
            break;
        case 3:
            print();
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return(0);
}

//TODO
void read() {

}

void input() {

    struct aNode *current;
    current = (struct aNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct aNode));

    int buff = 120;
    char temp[buff];

    printf("Enter data: ");
    fgets(temp, buff, stdin);
    sscanf(temp, "%[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %d%*c %f", 
           current->name, current->address, current->city, current->state,   
           &current->zip, &current->balance);                   

    insertSort(current);

    //only for testing
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %5d, $%9.2f\n", 
               current->name, current->address, current->city, 
               current->state, current->zip, current->balance);
}

void print() {

    struct aNode *p;

    for(p = dLList; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %5d, $%9.2f\n", 
              p->name, p->address, p->city, 
              p->state, p->zip, p->balance);
    }
}

//TODO
void delete() {

}

int insertSort(node * current) {

     struct aNode *p;
    struct aNode *q;

    p = (struct aNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct aNode));
    p = current;

    //need to link to previous node   
    if(dLList == NULL || strcmp(dLList->name, p->name) > 0) {
        p->next = dLList;
        p->prev = NULL;
        return(0);
    }else {
        q = dLList;
        while(q->next != NULL && strcmp(q->next->name, q->name) < 0) {
            q = q->next;
        }   
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next = p;
        return(0);
    }   
}
```

Output: , , , ,     0, $      0.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf` doesn't consume the newline at the end of the choice string. It is then read by the `fgets` call in `input()`, so the input string is empty (apart from the `\n` character).

This worked for me:

```
fgets(temp, buff, stdin);
sscanf(temp, "%d",&choice);
```

Comment: Worked, thanks :) And you said "worked for you"? Are you working on the same thing I am? :P 
And any advice on what AShelly wrote down below would be helpful. I don't quite understand what he/she is suggesting.

Comment: @beowulf3: The first time you insert, dLList is still NULL. You need it to point to the first element of the list, which is the one being inserted. That's why adding `dLList = p;` in the body of the `if` statement of `insertSort()` makes your code work.

Comment: Ohhh pffft. Me stupid. But how is that dealt with when inserting the second time, i.e. the if statement in insertSort() is false?

Answer (score 1):

Is `dLList` being initialized to NULL anywhere?
And if even if it is, is does not appear to get set to the first node when you insert a new node into an empty list.

Comment: No, the only "= NULL" occurs in insertSort(). "p->prev = NULL"

Comment: So it is not being initialzed at all. You need to set it to NULL at the beginning, and then in InsertSort, do `dLList = current;` whenever you insert a node at the head of the list (including the first one).

Comment: Beginning as in of main()? or before that? I put it before: errors galore. After: same problem of not printing.  

I placed "dLList = p;" inside the if statement in insertSort.